# python types: Literal of logging level as type?

Tags: python, types, mypy, literals

the following code:

```py
import logging

print(type(1))
print(type(logging.WARNING))
```

prints:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

yet, according to mypy, the first line of this code snippet is legal, but the second is not (Variable "logging.WARNING" is not valid as a type):

```py
OneOrTwo = Literal[1,2]  # ok
WarningOrError = Literal[logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR]  # not ok
```

I do not understand why the definition of OneOrTwo is ok but WarningOrError is not.

I would like also know what could be done to use a legal equivalent of WarningOrError, i.e. something I could use like this:

```py
def a(arg: WarningOrError)->None:
    pass
```

note: mypy redirects to https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases , but this did not clarify things for me.

Comment: `Literal` means just that: a *literal*, not a name or expression with the same value as a literal.

Comment: `logging` predates the `enum` module by quite a bit, or it almost certainly would have defined the various logging levels as an enumerated type, not just a handful of global variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Literal` only accepts literal arguments. PEP586 has very rigid definitions of what constitutes a "literal" in this context. You can read about it [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time). The problem with your definition of `WarningOrError` is that the actual definition of `logging.ERROR` and `WARNING` makes them *mutable* (you can look at the source code of `logging` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/__init__.py)), and hence illegal literals. *Constant* expressions like `1` or `2`, on the other hand, can be known statically (they never change!) and therefore are acceptable literals.

Among the accepted legal literals, `Enum` objects can help you achieve what you want:

```
import logging                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                      
from typing import Literal                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                      
from enum import Enum                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                      
class Log(Enum):                                                                                                                      
    ERROR = logging.ERROR                                                                                                             
    WARNING = logging.WARNING                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                      
LogType = Literal[Log.ERROR, Log.WARNING]

def a(arr: LogType):
    pass
```